# Will Ubuntu phone will be ported to other phones?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a samsung wave y (GT-S5380D) and willing to change a bada 2.0 on ubuntu. Bada has a lot of bugs and samsung has stopped developing it. For samsung wave I and wave II was the Ubuntu Phone port. Can I transfer my ubuntu on my mobile phone? Is Canonical engaged in porting to other phones?
thanks for your attention.